# HTML Footer in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 design view

Tags: css, html

I am working on getting the hang of HTML5/CSS and it is going OK thus far. I recently added a footer to my play website, and have it attached to the bottom of the page and centered. However, while the footer is centered correctly under my main content while previewing through a web browser, in the design view of Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 it shows the footer as way off to the side of the main content div. I find it odd it would appear this way in design view, but work as intended while testing. Is this just the cause of how I coded it? It is slightly annoying that I have to scroll way off to the right to see the footer in design view...

Any suggestions as to why this is, or any suggestions to the general coding, would be greatly appreciated. Below is how I coded in my footer. Thank you.

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #0033FF;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your CSS code indicates that it should be centered. If it is positioned to the left of the screen, then Dreamweaver is taking `position:absolute;` and automatically applying the effect of `left:0;`. I wouldn't take too much stock into how Dreamweaver's design view renders things, however, since no one will be viewing your website in there.

Comment: Adding margin:auto; might help...

Comment: Hmm. That did not change anything, but I actually think Dreamweaver is doing exactly what MrSlayer proposed. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

yes, its correct that Dreamweaver's output is quite different than that of web browser's output and there is nothing wrong with your code.

Dreamweaver's internal web browser is not much updated and doesn't supports some HTML and CSS tags.
so just ignore Dreamweaver's web browser..